# How to parse nested objects in JSON response

Tags: apex, json, map, deserialize, nested

Im trying to parse the below JSON response:

```
{  
      "preferredLanguage":"en",
      "preferredLocale":"en_GB",
      "languages":{  
         "en":{  
            "langCountry":"en-bn",
            "defaultLang":"en_GB"  
         }
      }
}
```

I can do this successfully if I create 3 classes with the third called 'en'. However I would like to avoid this as there may be other languages besides English. Is there a way to specify a key of 'en' to return the data within the 'en' object?  I have tried JSON.deserialiseUntyped with Maps of String, Object but I just get the error: 
System.TypeException: `Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to Map<String, Object>`

Here is the working class structure where I have hardcoded the class name "En":

```
public class countryLocale {
    public String preferredLanguage;
    public String preferredLocale;
    public Languages languages;

public class En {   
    public String langCountry;
    public String defaultLang;

}

public class Languages {
    public En en;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can address this effectively with a mix of collections and custom classes, like this:

```
public class countryLocale {
    public String preferredLanguage;
    public String preferredLocale;
    public Map<String, Locale> languages;
}
public class Locale {   
    public String langCountry;
    public String defaultLang;
}
```

That saves you from having to model each language statically as a property in a `Languages` class. Then, you can deserialize the data by doing

```
countryLocale l = (countryLocale)JSON.deserialize(
    jsonstr, 
    countryLocale.class
);
```

Comment: David thanks so much for the fast answer :) I've driven myself almost insane trying to figure this out today. Greatly appreciated